# Convert list of data frames to time series

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following list of data frames consisting of stock prices. Each data frame can potentially be of different length, and not all of the dates are in each data frame. I would like to convert the list to a time series with the first column being the date and each column being the price of a stock, with column names the name of the stock. If a price is missing for a given date, take the previous price.

```
$`0P00012DY5`<br/>
              last<br/>
2017-08-21 9.49504<br/>
2017-08-22 9.53553<br/>
2017-08-23 9.52643<br/>
2017-08-24 9.53486<br/>
2017-08-25 9.53390<br/>
2017-08-28 9.48788<br/>
2017-08-29 9.44059<br/>
2017-08-30 9.49893<br/>

$`0P0000KY8J`<br/>
               last<br/>
2017-08-21 11.58276<br/>
2017-08-22 11.58278<br/>
2017-08-23 11.58275<br/>
2017-08-24 11.58263<br/>
2017-08-25 11.58260<br/>
2017-08-29 11.58250<br/>
2017-08-30 11.58246<br/>
2017-08-31 11.58237<br/>
```

Desired output

```
date    0P00012DY5      0P0000KY8J<br/>
2017-08-21  9.49504         11.58276<br/>
2017-08-22  9.53553         11.58278<br/>
2017-08-23  9.52643         11.58275<br/>
2017-08-24  9.53486         11.58263<br/>
2017-08-25  9.53390         11.58260<br/>
2017-08-28  9.48788         11.58260<br/>
2017-08-29  9.44059         11.58250<br/>
2017-08-30  9.49893         11.58246<br/>
2017-08-31  9.49893         11.58237<br/>
```

Structure of the list:

```
mod_ll <- structure(list(`0P00012DY5` = structure(list(last = c(9.49504, 
9.53553, 9.52643, 9.53486, 9.5339, 9.48788, 9.44059, 9.49893, 
9.542, 9.56865, 9.5417, 9.54301, 9.52942, 9.54246, 9.54653, 9.60182, 
9.63157, 9.62566, 9.64084, 9.62746, 9.65814, 9.6672, 9.66387)), .Names = "last", row.names = c("2017-08-21", 
"2017-08-22", "2017-08-23", "2017-08-24", "2017-08-25", "2017-08-28", 
"2017-08-29", "2017-08-30", "2017-08-31", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-04", 
"2017-09-05", "2017-09-06", "2017-09-07", "2017-09-08", "2017-09-11", 
"2017-09-12", "2017-09-13", "2017-09-14", "2017-09-15", "2017-09-18", 
"2017-09-19", "2017-09-20"), class = "data.frame"), `0P0000KY8J` = structure(list(
    last = c(11.58276, 11.58278, 11.58275, 11.58263, 11.5826, 
    11.58254, 11.5825, 11.58246, 11.58237, 11.58231, 11.58223, 
    11.58219, 11.58218, 11.58206, 11.58202, 11.58197, 11.58193, 
    11.58189, 11.58178, 11.58174, 11.58173, 11.58166, 11.58163
    )), .Names = "last", row.names = c("2017-08-21", "2017-08-22", 
"2017-08-23", "2017-08-24", "2017-08-25", "2017-08-28", "2017-08-29", 
"2017-08-30", "2017-08-31", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-04", "2017-09-05", 
"2017-09-06", "2017-09-07", "2017-09-08", "2017-09-11", "2017-09-12", 
"2017-09-13", "2017-09-14", "2017-09-15", "2017-09-18", "2017-09-19", 
"2017-09-20"), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("0P00012DY5", 
"0P0000KY8J"))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` based solution can be to combine all your data.frames from list using `dplyr::bind_rows`. Then separate `Date` and `Value` in 2 columns and change data in `wide` format using `tidyr::spread`.

Finally, for missing dates, use `tidyr::fill` to populate last available values.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(ll, .id="Name") %>% 
  separate(last, c("Date", "Value"), sep=" ") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  spread(Name, Value) %>%
  fill(2:3)

#         Date 0P0000KY8J 0P00012DY5
# 1 2017-08-21   11.58276    9.49504
# 2 2017-08-22   11.58278    9.53553
# 3 2017-08-23   11.58275    9.52643
# 4 2017-08-24   11.58263    9.53486
# 5 2017-08-25   11.58260    9.53390
# 6 2017-08-28   11.58260    9.48788
# 7 2017-08-29   11.58250    9.44059
# 8 2017-08-30   11.58246    9.49893
# 9 2017-08-31   11.58237    9.49893
```

**Edited:** Updated to include answer for modified data provided by OP. The `Date` is provided as rownames of `data.frames`. We need to move `Date` to column before merging data frames. One can use `rownames_to_column` with `lapply` on list to move `rownames` to column.

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(lapply(mod_ll,rownames_to_column, var="Date"), .id="Name") %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  spread(Name, last) %>%
  fill(2:3)

#         Date 0P0000KY8J 0P00012DY5
# 1  2017-08-21   11.58276    9.49504
# 2  2017-08-22   11.58278    9.53553
# 3  2017-08-23   11.58275    9.52643
# 4  2017-08-24   11.58263    9.53486
# 5  2017-08-25   11.58260    9.53390
# 6  2017-08-28   11.58254    9.48788
#
#....so on
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text =  
"last
'2017-08-21 9.49504'
'2017-08-22 9.53553'
'2017-08-23 9.52643'
'2017-08-24 9.53486'
'2017-08-25 9.53390'
'2017-08-28 9.48788'
'2017-08-29 9.44059'
'2017-08-30 9.49893'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- read.table(text = 
"last
'2017-08-21 11.58276'
'2017-08-22 11.58278'
'2017-08-23 11.58275'
'2017-08-24 11.58263'
'2017-08-25 11.58260'
'2017-08-29 11.58250'
'2017-08-30 11.58246'
'2017-08-31 11.58237'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ll <- list(df1, df2)

names(ll) <- c('0P00012DY5', '0P0000KY8J')
```

Comment: @marcl Fantastic. Please remove the comments from above chat as those will not help future users.